# unsatisfied link error in java native programming

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native

I am trying to build my first native program in java.The .c and .h file compiled well but when running java code I get this error.
Here are my java and c source file

**Main.java**

```
public class Main{
  public native void sayHello();
  static{
       System.loadLibrary("hello");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main main = new Main();
        main.sayHello();
  }
}
```

**Hello.c**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    printf("Hello World \n");
    return;

}
```

**.C file compilation**

```
C:.../gcc -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\include" -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\include\win32" -o hello.dll -shared Hello.c
```

**Running Java File**

```
C:.../javac Main.java
C:.../java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Main.sayHello()V
    at Main.sayHello(Native Method)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: Please post your Command Prompt output as text, not as images. This makes searching for similar issues much easier.

Comment: `-o hello.dell`? It should be `hello.dll`. It is a typo in your question or did you actually name your library `hello.dell`?

Comment: Sorry it is typo in question .edited that..my mistake.. I have got hello.dll file problem it with running java file

Answer (score 0):

Is the new DLL's directory either the Java app's working directory, in the system PATH variable, or in the "java.library.path" JVM variable? If not, this exception will be thrown because the JVM won't be able to find the DLL.

I'm not sure what the error message format you got means, though. Normally if a library can't be found by the JVM, the error is something like `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no library_name in java.library.path`, but yours is different.

Comment: my dll file is in same folder where i compiled java and .c file (i.e same directory). I used <java -Djava.library.path=""> also but same error..

Comment: But do you run the Java app in this directory, or in another? Try running the Java app with the DLL in the app's working directory, using `-Djava.library.path="."`, and see what occurs. Note: the library path I just mentioned is not empty, but the one you last posted is empty.

Comment: Dear, I mentioned it empty here to summarize it.There I used it like  `>java -Djava.library.path="C:/Documents and Settings/User/Desktop/Native" Main`